# UINavigationController transition delegate

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uinavigationcontroller

I have implemented UINavigationControllerDelegate method:

```
public func navigationController(navigationController: UINavigationController, animationControllerForOperation operation: UINavigationControllerOperation, fromViewController fromVC: UIViewController, toViewController toVC: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? { }
```

because I had to set application state and only "event" that was able to capture `Pop transition` of my `UINavigationController` was this method. Everything is working properly but as far as that functionality is concerned, but now my swipe back action does not work (only pressing back button works).

At the end of this method I have returned nil because I had no idea what its doing but apparently it affects that swipe to back functionality.

Is there any default `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` that I can returned to have that swipe back functionality?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I switched to this delegate method:

```
public func navigationController(navigationController: UINavigationController, willShowViewController viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) { 
    if self.viewControllerCount - 1 == self.rootController.viewControllers.count {
       // Pop action, do additional logic
   }
}
```

and customized it so that I can know for sure if its pop action (tracking last number of view controllers.